# Maximum number of concurrent LOAD FROM S3 requests in Aurora Mysql

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I've been using the LOAD FROM S3 feature of Aurora Mysql. To max out the box and the bandwidth, I submitted 30 concurrent requests for S3 load. On checking the processlist in Mysql, I see only 4 S3 LOAD queries running at any point in time. Is that a hard limit? Or am I doing something incorrect?

Here are my scripts for submitting the loads:

Single LOAD from S3:

```
cat load-one-table.sh

export MYSQL_PWD=[REDACTED]
echo "Shard #$1"
mysql -u [REDACTED] -B -e "load data from s3 's3://A/B/C/D' into table DB.table_"$1;
```

Concurrent LOADS:

```
cat parallel-load.sh

for i in $(seq 1 $1); do
        echo "Starting Task #$i"
        nohup ./load-one-table.sh $i &
        echo "Submitted Task #$i"
done
```

Trigger:

```
./parallel-load 30
```

I do see all 30 requests submitted in nohup logs.

Explciitly checking if all loads are running on the client:

```
ps auxww | grep -c "load-one-table"
31

# The result shows 31, since there is one extra process match for the grep
```

Checking accepted requests on the server:

```
show full processlist;
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User      | Host                | db                 | Command | Time | State       | Info                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 606 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Query   |   60 | executing   | load data from s3 's3://REDACTED' into table REDACTED_2 |
| 607 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Query   |   60 | executing   | load data from s3 's3://REDACTED' into table REDACTED_4 |
| 608 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Query   |   60 | executing   | load data from s3 's3://REDACTED' into table REDACTED_1 |
| 609 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Query   |   60 | executing   | load data from s3 's3://REDACTED' into table REDACTED_3 |
| 610 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 611 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 612 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 613 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 614 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 615 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 616 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 617 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 618 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 619 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 620 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 621 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 622 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 623 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 624 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 625 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 626 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 627 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 628 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 629 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 630 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 631 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 632 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 633 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 634 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
| 635 | REDACTED  | localhost           | NULL               | Sleep   |   60 | cleaning up | NULL                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I would expect to see all load requests running. How are you issuing the LOAD queries?

Comment: @MCI I added some snippets for my workload.

Comment: do you see all 30 processes running on your server? (e.g. ps -ef | grep parallel-load). Additionally, have you been able to determine if after a LOAD statement completes a different LOAD statement takes its place? (i.e. if it appears the statements are being queued on the server)

Comment: All 30 loads completed, and I verified the counts in all the 30 tables. So it did execute fully. And yes, all 30 processes were running on the client as well. I do think the server accepted all the requests, as process list showed 4 queries and a bunch of others in unknown state.

Comment: @MCI Added some more details on the question.